# LoadSaveReportException was unhandled / Invalid report file path

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, crystal-reports

This is my first time using Crystal reports.
What i am trying to do is 
when i highlight a row in `datagridview` and click report button,
only the highlighted row will be displayed in the Crystal report viewer just like shown in the image.

[image]

Report Button code

```
  Private Sub btnReport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReport.Click
        Dim report As New ReportDocument
        report.SetParameterValue("StudentRecord", dgv1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value)
        report.Load("C:\Users\harold\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SASApp\SASApp\MyReport.rpt")
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

Whenever i click the report button, i get an error of

> LoadSaveReportException was unhandled / Invalid report file path with
>   this line

```
report.SetParameterValue("StudentRecord", dgv1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value)
```

I get the `"StudentRecord"` in the parameter fields that I made in Crystal report as the image below shown

[image]

Can anyone help me to figure out whats wrong with my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to load the report first before you set the parameters. It's trying to set the parameter to a report that isn't loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the big help